# Google Contacts API Update contact - not found

Tags: php, updates, google-contacts-api, http-status-code-401

So, I can retrieve contacts and insert contacts, but I'm having a problem updating contacts. All I get is a 404 "Not found" error. The xml is well-formed, since I can do the inserts, but it seems that the URL I'm using doesn't work? I have tried:

```
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/{my email}/full/{contact id}
```

I have also tried:

```
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/{contact id}
```

and also used the ID that comes back from the retrieval query:

```
http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/{my email}/base/{contact id}
```

The headers I'm sending are:

```
Content-Type: application/atom+xml
Depth: 1
Authorization: Bearer {Auth Code}
GData-Version: 3.0
If-Match: *
```

More Details:
I have modified my code so that when it does the GET of the contact, it grabs the edit link from the contact XML:

```
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/awallace%40ihouseweb.com/full/{contactID}
```

And uses that for the URL, and ensured that I am using a "PUT" by:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PUT, true);
```

And now it behaves differently - it says that I need to login:

```
<internalReason>Login Required</internalReason>
```

Even though my Auth token is valid for another hour. Arg.

thanks,
andy

Comment: Have you tried sending the same request in Oauth2.0 Playground? here is the link :  https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/

Comment: Well, THAT's a cool item. Didn't know about the playground, very nice. I played around with it, testing several things, but still getting the error. Here are the headers I'm sending...
  
POST /m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/2626b2cb88801ac0 HTTP/1.1  
Host: www.google.com  
Gdata-version: 3.0  
Content-length: 2212  
Depth: 1  
If-match: *  
Content-type: application/atom+xml  
Authorization: Bearer <auth code>

Comment: Should `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PUT, true);` be `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");` instead? Are you trying to `PUT` a file or `PUT` with a data body? See http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2009/putting-data-fields-with-php-curl and http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php.

Comment: Wow, yes it should be. Thanks, I think this is getting beaten into shape now. Thanks for the help, everyone.